# VSCode Syntax error for php inside js file

Tags: javascript, php, visual-studio-code, gettext

I'm passing gettext inside strings in .js.php files (which are mostly javascript files), I've already added a file association for javascript in my settings.json but vscode adds squiggles under the strings since it's not recognizing the php. Is there a solution other than changing the file type everytime.

Heres an example.

```
columns.push(this.getColumnField({
   name: 'description',
   header: "<?=_("Description")?>",
   type: 'text'
}));
```

the 'header' portion is underlined in red. Changing the quotes is not an option as the codebase has multiple thousands of these types of thing.

Comment: perhaps turn things off, it can be one or the other not both `"files.associations": { "*.js.php": "plaintext"},`

Comment: That's a bad idea anyway. What if your text contains quotes?